# The application I'm developing does not appear or open in my android device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am currently building an application in Android Studio. When I run my application and Android Studio installs it on my device through the USB, the application doesn't open and doesn't show up in the **Apps** list of my device. Which is strange because when I travel to **Settings > Application Manager** in the device, it shows my application as if installed but I can't open it. I also have tested the application in the Nexus emulator and it opens up just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a `intent-filter` in your "main" activity so that it can show in the launcher. below is an example:

```
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

replace "MainActivity" with the name of the activity you want to show in the launcher.